# Angular ng-change not working for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

Here is my code below. The ng-change of individual checkboxes is not getting triggered when it is changed by clicking **Select All** button but it is getting triggered when it's selected individually. I need the `itemChecked` method to be triggered when the **Select All** button is clicked.

Here is a [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/vishnuys/pen/GxqByj) for the same

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="Test">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <form>
      <div ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item" ng-change="itemChecked($index)">{{$index + 1}}
      </div>
    </form>
    <button ng-click="toggleSelection()">Select all</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module("Test", []);
app.controller("TestController", [
  "$scope",
  "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.list = [false, false, false, false, false];

    $scope.itemChecked = function(i) {
      console.log(i);
    };

    $scope.toggleSelection = function() {
      for (var i in $scope.list) {
        $scope.list[i] = true;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Please let me know what I need to change or what I am doing wrong to fix this.

Comment: Yes, it will not trigger if you check it by manually (by code). It's browser behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set wrong variable in `ng-model`. The ng-model section should be:

```
ng-model="list[$index]"
```

To listen the collection, you have to use the following:

```
$scope.$watchCollection
```

It is working perfectly in the following code, check the code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("Test", []);
app.controller("TestController", [
  "$scope",
  "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.list = [false, false, false, false, false];
    $scope.itemChecked = function(i) {
      console.log(i);
      console.log($scope.list[i]);
    };
    $scope.$watchCollection('list', function (oldValue, newValue) {
    //console.log(oldValue);
    //console.log(newValue);
    //console.log($scope.list);
    for(var i = 0; i < oldValue.length;i++){
      if (oldValue[i]!==newValue[i]) {
         $scope.itemChecked(i);
      }
    }
    });
    $scope.toggleSelection = function() {
      for (var i in $scope.list) {
        $scope.list[i] = true;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Test">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <form>
      <div ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="list[$index]" ng-change="itemChecked($index)">{{$index + 1}}
      </div>
    </form>
    <button ng-click="toggleSelection()">Select all</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear before, I have updated the question. It is not getting when clicked on **Select All** button. The individual checkboxes are getting triggered just fine.

Comment: I want the `itemChecked` method to be called when the **Select All** button is clicked. That is still not happening in the updated code.

Comment: Still, the method `itemChecked` is not being called with the updated code.

Comment: No need to call the method: if its required, then call manually from $scope.$watchCollection. Every single item change or all will fire the $scope.$watchCollection.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) method. [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) works only if the value is changed from HTML. It is  not triggered when the value is changed from controller.

```
app.controller("TestController", [
  "$scope",
  "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.list = [false, false, false, false, false];

    $scope.itemChecked = function(i) {
      console.log(i);
    };

    $scope.toggleSelection = function() {
      for (var i in $scope.list) {
        $scope.list[i] = true;
      }
    };


    /*********************************************************/        
    $scope.$watchCollection('list', function (newVal, oldVal) {   
           console.log('collection changed') });
    }
   /*********************************************************/      

]);
```

Or If you just want `itemChecked` method to be called whenever the **selectAll** button is clicked, Then just call `itemChecked` inside `toggleSelection` method.

```
$scope.toggleSelection = function() {
      for (var i in $scope.list) {
        $scope.list[i] = true;
        $scope.itemChecked(i);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Where and how do I use `$scope.watch` method? Can you give me more details about it?

Comment: I want the `itemChecked` method to be called when the **Select All** button is clicked. How would I achieve that?

Comment: `I want the itemChecked method to be called when the Select All button is clicked` ? If there is not other logic involved, and you just want to call  `itemChecked` method , then whey don't you just call that inside `toggleSelection` method.  In this way, when you click **selectAll** button, it will call `toggleSelection` and after toggling the status, it just invokes `itemChecked`

Comment: That actually works, Thank you. If you can add this to the answer, I'll accept it.